# Coefficient of $x^{18}$ in the given equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to find the coefficient of $x^{18}$ in

$$(1+x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots +18x^{18})^2?$$

Obviously expanding is not the way to go,
do you know any method of some sort?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Expanding seems perfectly fine... you should see that it will be $1\cdot 18 + 2\cdot 17+3\cdot 16 + \dots + 17\cdot 2+18\cdot 1$.  Now... as for simplifying this... $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{18}k(19-k) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{18}19k - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{18}k^2$, both of which should be in known forms.

Comment: Alternatively, first express your polynomial as a truncation of the infinite series for a rational function, and then work with that. But are you sure you don't want $x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots$, or maybe $1+2x+3x^2+\cdots$?

Comment: $1\cdot 18 + 1\cdot 17 + 2\cdot 16 + \dots + 17\cdot 1 + 18 \cdot  1$ unless @GerryMyerson's comment prompts a correction from the OP.

Comment: Ah, good catch @NickD yes, I missed that there were two coefficients who were $1$.  In that case, $1\cdot 18 + (1\cdot 17+2\cdot 16 + \dots + 16\cdot 2 + 17\cdot 1) + 18\cdot 1$ in which case my earlier suggestion only applies to the center and the $+18$'s can be handled separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding isn't as hard as it looks (*if* you avoid typos like $4x^3$ instead of $4x^4$!), the result is $$324x^{36} + 612x^{35} + 865x^{34} + 1084x^{33} + 1270x^{32} + 1424x^{31} + 1547x^{30} + 1640x^{29} + 1704x^{28} + 1740x^{27} + 1749x^{26} + 1732x^{25} + 1690x^{24} + 1624x^{23} + 1535x^{22} + 1424x^{21} + 1292x^{20} + 1140x^{19} + 1005x^{18} + 850x^{17} + 712x^{16} + 590x^{15} + 483x^{14} + 390x^{13} + 310x^{12} + 242x^{11} + 185x^{10} + 138x^{9} + 100x^{8} + 70x^{7} + 47x^{6} + 30x^{5} + 18x^{4} + 10x^{3} + 5x^{2} + 2x + 1$$ (obtained with Pari/GP). Of course, you can also extend the polynomial to a power series, $$1+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2},$$ the higher order terms won't change the result. The square is $$1+2\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^4},$$ so the coefficient in question would be
$$-2\binom{-2}{17}+\binom{-4}{16}=36+969=1005.$$